# Payment Intent issues Stripe Connect

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am developing a small online marketplace in WordPress for a client and I am using Stripe Connect. What I am trying to accomplish is:

1. User A is posting a project, User B bids for this project, gets accepted and delivers the work.
2. User A now has to pay the agreed amount for the deliverable
3. User A gets his card charges, Platform account gets the application fee, Stripe gets the Stripe fee, User B gets paid with the remaining amount

I have created the following function with payment intent, destination charge and application amount fee as described here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide

```
function destination_charge(){

// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$payment_intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'amount' => 1000,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'application_fee_amount' => 123,
    'transfer_data' => [
      'destination' => 'acct_UserB',
    ],
  ]);
}
```

So if I understand the docs and the concept correctly, when User A triggers the above function, User A gets charged $10 on his card, application takes $1.23 fee and User B gets the remaining amount. Stripe deducts its service fee from the application. Although I am not charging anything from a form, since User A is a verified connected account with card details already in Stripe Connect.

Unfortunately this is not the case though and even if I try separating charges from transfers, as described here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers, it's not working either.

Stripe Connect is setup for US businesses, USD currency. I am using Express Accounts on a test environment.
Side note: I already tried using top-ups in order to add test funds and create balance, but the "add to balance" button is not available for some reason. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/top-ups

What am I missing here? Is destination charges the right choice for what I am trying to accomplish?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you just initially move the money on your personal bank account, and then if the client accept the order, make a payment to the seller, otherwise refund the client?

Comment: You mean like transfer money from User A to the platform account and then transfer from the platform account to User B?

Comment: yes something like this, so you will take tha part of a "middle point" where you temporarily deposit the money until they decide what to do

Comment: So you what you are saying is described here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create Unfortunately, this is not working though. It throws out an error "The 'destination' param cannot be set to your own account". Which means that you cannot specify the platform accoun IDt as the destination in the transfer.

Comment: This seems fine as long as `acct_UserB` is a different account ID that is connected to your "platform" account. Can you elaborate on the error you're seeing? You'll also need to confirm the PaymentIntent client side with Stripe.js using stripe.confirmCardPayment passing in the Stripe.js element. Destination charges seem fine for this. Is it that the balance isn't available yet? (There are test cards for skipping the waiting period)

Comment: Yes `acct_UserB` is indeed another connected account. I believe you are referring to this: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide#accept-payment for the client side confirmation. What I don't understand though is why would User A need a frontend form to fill in his/her card in order to trigger a payment intent. I mean User A is already a connected account and the card details are inside his/her Stripe Connect ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the `stripe-account` header. By using this, you are simply making the request on-behalf of the connected account. The payment will automatically be credited to the connected account.

```
$payment_intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'amount' => 1000,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'application_fee_amount' => 123,
  ], ['stripe-account' => 'acct_UserB']);
}

\Stripe\PaymentIntent::confirm(
    $payment_intent->id,
    ['payment_method' => 'pm_card_visa']
);
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. This throws out the following error: "Can only apply an application_fee_amount when the PaymentIntent is attempting a direct payment (using an OAuth key or Stripe-Account header) or destination payment (using `transfer_data[destination]`)"

Comment: It should work as stated in here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges. Did you add the ```stripe-account``` header as a second param?

Comment: Hi Kim. so based on your suggestion and after contacting Stripe support, I managed to resolve it by using the separate charges and transfers as described in the docs link you provided above. So essentially Account A doesn't have to be a connected account, instead it can just be a customer. The payment intent "create" and "confirm" makes the charge while the transfer sends the amount to Account B. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @vsapountzis Happy to help!